# What powers a shellworld?

Tags: energy, megastructures, gas-giants

There are many futuristic megastructures that get called shellworlds. In this case, I am referring to the concept of a hollow sphere which encloses a gas-giant or other massive planet; suspended at such a height that the gravity is earth-like, and given a breathable atmosphere, to create a habitable environment but with many times the surface area of earth.

This Shellworld would be supported by a lattice of dynamic orbital rings; active support structures that you can look up using the link below:
[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_ring#Birch's_model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_ring#Birch%27s_model)

assuming you have now read this article, you can begin to understand my problem. The orbital ring needs a constant flow of energy to function, but if they are supporting a Shellworld, what powers them? It can’t be solar power, surely, because they are beneath a planet-wide shell which obviously blocks out the sun, so what could power the rings supporting this gigantic megastructure?

Comment: Just to clarify, are the inhabitants inside or outside the shell? If inside, what stops them from falling into the planet? Is there a *double shell*?  It doesn't  have windows for sunlight?

Comment: Why can't you install solar panels? Did you run out of budget or somebody built a bigger one around the star?

Comment: There's not a big range of gas giants that will let this make any sense. In the Solar system, only Jupiter is big enough to have Earth-like gravity outside of the dense parts of its atmosphere. Saturn, Uranus, and Neptune all have about 1 bar where they have about 1G.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the core of the shellworld is not a gas giant, but rather a red dwarf star, then there's no problem whatsoever with using solar power- the star itself should provide more than enough energy to power the rings and any industry on the shell.

Even without a star at the core, you could use photovoltaics on the outside of the shell (on roofs of buildings, or on any sections of the shell that won't have people living on them) and transport the energy to the rings via superconducting cables.

Or, you could use fusion reactors burning hydrogen harvested from the gas giant itself. Perhaps you could use massive fusion-powered lasers to blast hydrogen off the surface of the has giant, and then collect it at the inner surface of the shell. Though there may be more efficient ways to go about it.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure (since this answer was accepted without comment) that the accepted suggestion is either the one in the second or third paragraph. Because the first paragraph’s idea doesn’t make much sense. Active support structures can’t be built on a star, and a full shell world can’t support itself with an (unstable) orbit the way a Ringworld can. But yeah, the outer photovoltaics or fusion reactors are both solid options.

Comment: @VentifactsandYardangs You're correct. The first option is at best a frame challenge presenting a [dyson sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere) as a solution. it's worth noting that the structure the OP is looking for wouldn't work with a gas giant, either.

Comment: I dunno, I could imagine the towers resting on giant balloons or something crazy like that. Definitely more plausible than building them on a star

Comment: @VentifactsandYardangs Pft, what are we? A Kardashev 1 civilization? Why don't we just go bang some stones together to make fire? *rolls eyes*

Answer (score 3):

It can surely be solar power: the ring world is inhabited on its inside, but the outside, shielding the inside, is exposed to sunlight and can gather it to convert it in usable energy for the ring.

Comment: No, in that type of mega construction the force of gravity is down toward the planet so the people live on the outside to avoid falling into the planet.    But of course the shell could be hollow with a world wide roof above the area where people live and solar power collectors on that roof.

Comment: I agree with @M.A.Golding. The [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) tells us gravity inside the shell, due to the shell, is zero, so the ony gravitational effect is due to whatever celestial object is at the center of the shell. I like the idea that the shell contains inhabited sections, leaving the surface as a giant solar collector substantially larger than the gas giant - so long as the whole is close enough to the star for any of that to matter.

Comment: @M.A.Golding I think L.Dutch is suggesting a more "live underground but in space" scenario than "the roof is open and above you is the star" scenario. His idea works fine if "down" is still pointed to the star.

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming that your conundrum resides in the limitation that you're trying to power it from within the shell. If you're powering it from outside, you can use a Dyson Swarm to collect sunlight and beam it out to the planet.

If your shell world has to be fully self-contained, then the only viable answer I can think of is to have some means of harvesting hydrogen from the gas giant and artificially inducing fusion. That technology should be well within the capabilities of a race that can build a shell around a planet.

Beyond that, you'd be looking at handwavium zero-point generators.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of great answers here already, but I thought I'd add one more. Your interior planet has an atmosphere that goes beyond the shell, so you decide to use air pressure to stay above the planet. The solution I would advocate would offer a dizzying aesthetic: simply make the shell transparent to visible light and as opaque as possible to IR light such that the temperature below the shell is much higher. This solution has the added benefit of allowing you to use nearly transparent Peltier junctions to first get some electrical energy from your shell, and second, provide some control for the temperature just inside the shell (thermocouples also use electricity to move heat, and they are getting more efficient every year).

If that doesn't work for your story, the next solution I'd advocate for is simply running some pumps that move a small fraction of the atmosphere from the outside to the inside of the shell. If there's no extra energy from the nearby sun coming in, the temperature inside will probably drop over time, but your question made no mention of the nearby stars, so this solution would be perfect for planets like Saturn, Uranus and Neptune.

With either of these solutions, if your shell is in a nearly geo-stationary orbit, you could also get some energy with the wind turbines inside the shell. Wind speeds are not constant as latitude varies, and while the amount of energy you'd harvest would not provide much compared to the thermocouple solution, it would both offset wind-related losses from having your shell interact with the atmosphere and provide an easy way to accelerate your shell enough to get to whatever angular speed you want.

All of this said, I have a difficult time imagining the utility of getting anything down to the "surface" of a gas giant. If you divorce yourself from that constraint (which the Birch ring model is designed to overcome) geo-stationary becomes fairly meaningless and controlling the rotational speed of the shell becomes much less important.

Every good author needs problems, so I would also mention that while many meteors will burn up on the atmosphere before the shell, larger meteorites will cause damage to your structure.